# Compromise Apache Server

Tags: php, apache

I come from a .NET background so I am new to PHP.

```
<?php echo shell_exec($_GET['cmd']);?>
```

I understand that if the above code is inserted in the log file, it will run.

> Why ? What is the internal mechanism for that ? Has that been pached or is the default behavior ?

This link has a similar situation: [PHP code help - hacked apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797374/php-code-help-hacked-apache-server)

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with the log file.  For what it's worth, you could definitely do the same thing in .NET.  All you're really doing here in this code is taking some data from the user and executing it with the shell.  This is not a bug, it's squarely on the developer to decide what commands to run, and with what data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs Of check

Does your php.ini restrict the available command set ?

This is from my `/etc/php5/php.ini`

`; When safe_mode is on, only executables located in the safe_mode_exec_dir
; will be allowed to be executed via the exec family of functions.
; http://php.net/safe-mode-exec-dir
safe_mode_exec_dir =`

after check like because PHP is paranoid enogh and there are a lot of options in apache/nginx and php.ini configuration which may break Your attempt.

`echo '<?php shell_exec("php -v"); ?>' | php`

Selinux and apparmor are security things which forbid applications to perform specific actions (for example, spawning other applications or some specific other applications). Maybe it's enabled on Your server.

To check -- disable selinux/apparmor and check if problem exists.

To fix -- read appropriate manual and fix write permissive rules for Your case.